# Como funciona a responsividade no desenvolvimento IOS com Swift 4 no xCode ?

Tags: ios, swift, mac

Bom galera, estou começando agora a entrar na programação IOS, e estou com essa dúvida na minha cabeça, pelo que eu vi, a galera trabalha muito arrastando os objetos e programando-os, porém, **como funciona a responsividade nisso?**

Apenas arrastar os objetos e programa-los já se adequa a todos os iphone ? ou não ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Responsividade está ligada a fazer um layout que se adeque para uma gama de devices. Dentro do Xcode ele te dar uma ferramenta chamada constraints. usando isso o próprio xcode faz os cálculos necessários para cada tela. infelizmente é uma parada que dá muito trabalho e acontece muito warning. É uma parte bastante visual do projeto, então eu te indico a procurar vídeos sobre constraints pra isso.

Comment: Bom, eu acho que responde sim, não foi lá muita ajuda, porém deu pra dar uma entendida.